# Why the class attribute does not always appear as key in the instance's dictionary?

Tags: python, class, object, oop, attributes

I was reading about OOP in python on this section about [Attributes](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_object_oriented_programming.php#Attributes) and was literally shocked by the below example.

I am not getting why the dictionary of an instance (whose `class` is given a new attribute) is empty:

```
class Robot(object):
    pass

x = Robot()
Robot.brand = "Kuka"
x.brand
```

Output:

```
'Kuka'
```

---

```
x.brand = "Thales"
Robot.brand
```

Output:

```
'Kuka'
```

---

```
y = Robot()
y.brand
```

Output:

```
'Kuka'
```

---

```
Robot.brand = "Thales"
y.brand
```

Output:

```
'Thales'
```

---

```
x.brand
```

Output:

```
'Thales'
```

---

If you look at the `__dict__` dictionaries, you can see what's happening:

```
x.__dict__
```

Output:

```
{'brand': 'Thales'}
```

---

```
y.__dict__
```

Output:

```
{}
```

Another quote from same website:

> If you try to access y.brand, Python checks first, if "brand" is a key of the y.`__dict__` dictionary. If it is not, Python checks if "brand" is a key of the Robot.`__dict__`. If so, the value can be retrieved.

**My question is:** Why does `y.__dict__` give an empty dictionary? What is the logic and mechanism behind it?

Answer (score 0):

Why would it have one? Instances do not automatically copy class attributes (that would be unexpected and inefficient). Your `y` object doesn't have any instance attributes (`y.brand` is simply a proxy to `Robot.brand` because of the quote from the documentation you posted in your question), hence its `.__dict__` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [this tutorial on `__dict__`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-does-built-in-class-attribute-dict-do-in-Python), we can see the following code sample (slightly modified from original):

```
class MyClass(object):
    class_var = 1

    def __init__(self, i_var):
        self.i_var = i_var

foo = MyClass(2)
bar = MyClass(3)

print(foo.__dict__)
print(bar.__dict__)
```

With the following output:

```
{'i_var': 2}
{'i_var': 3}
```

As you can see, the output of `foo.__dict__` and `bar.__dict__` *do not* include `class_var`. This is the case with all classes; `__dict__` does not list class-wide attributes.

Looking at your entire program:

```
class Robot(object):
    pass
x = Robot()
Robot.brand = "Kuka"
x.brand
x.brand = "Thales"
Robot.brand
y = Robot()
y.brand
Robot.brand = "Thales" # Sets class variable
y.brand
x.brand
x.__dict__
y.__dict__
```

We can see that, at the time `x` and `y` were created, `Robot.brand` was set to `"Kuka"`. We also see that there was an explicit declaration setting `x.brand` to `"Thales"`; however, it does not include a `y.brand = "Whatever"` declaration.

In other words, the value of `y.brand` is inherited from the class attribute `Robot.brand`, and class attributes are not listed with `__dict__`. On the other hand, `x.brand` is specifically set to `"Thales"`, so `x.brand` is now referring to an object-specific variable, meaning it will show up in a `__dict__` listing.

Answer (score 0):

When you attempt to access a method or attribute in an instance, then python first asks the instance if the instance has such a thing. If not, then python asks the parent if the parent has that thing, etc. Python continues climbing the layers of inheritance till it finds something or it raises and error. For example,

```
class A: 
    x = 9
```

"x" is a class variable and exists with the class. Hence, ALL instances have "x" attribute automatically, unless they override their own attribute.

```
I = A()
print(I.x) #prints 9, python asks the parent for "x" since I didn't have an "x"
I.x = 10    
print(I.x) #prints 10, python returns what I already has, doesn't ask parent

Z = A() 
print(Z.x) #prints 9, python asks the parent for "x" since Z didn't have an "x"
```

This is very memory efficient. For example, this means that all instances share a "global" (global with respect to the class) variable. Hence, only one copy of A.x is written in memory. The only time python writes another "x" value in memory is if an instance changed their "x" value explicitly. So generating a million instances of A does not make a million copies of the value at A.x.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `id(<object>)` to check what's going on.

Declaration of a new empty class Robot

```
    class Robot(object):
    ...     pass
    ... 
    Robot
    <class '__main__.Robot'>
    Robot.__dict__
    mappingproxy({'__module__': '__main__', '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'Robot' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'Robot' objects>, '__doc__': None})
```

New instance of `Robot` class

```
    x = Robot()
    x
    <__main__.Robot object at 0x0000022811C8A978>
```

The `x` instance is empty

```
    x.__dict__
    {}
```

New class property `brand` is defined

```
Robot.brand = "Kuka"
Robot.brand
'Kuka'
```

If we try to access `x.brand`, Python will look for `brand` in `x.__dict__`, find nothing so it goes to `Robot.__dict__` and find the class property `brand`.

```
x.brand
'Kuka'
```

We can verify that we are actually seen the same

```
id(Robot.brand)
2371120205752
id(x.brand)
2371120205752
```

New instance property `brand` is defined

```
x.brand = "Thales"
```

And the class property `brand` remains unaltered

```
Robot.brand
'Kuka'
```

We can verify that we are actually seen two different properties

```
id(x.brand)
2371119992200
id(Robot.brand)
2371120205752
```

New instance `y` is created and is empty

```
y = Robot()
y.__dict__
{}
```

We can verify that is a new one:

```
id(y)
2371119989200
```

If we try to access `y.brand`, Python will look for `brand` in `y.__dict__`, found nothing so then goes to `Robot.__dict__` and find the class property `brand`.

```
y.brand
'Kuka'
```

And we can verify that the id is the same of `Robot.brand`. So `y` is a reference to `Robot.brand`

```
id(y.brand)
2371120205752
```

If we modify class property `brand`

```
Robot.brand = "Thales"
id(Robot.brand)
2371119992200
```

`y.brand` is modified because at this moment isn't an instance property but a reference to class property `Robot.brand`. We can check the id of `y.brand` is the same as `Robot.brand`.

```
y.brand
'Thales'
id(y.brand)
2371119992200
```

Now we can check that `x` has an instance property `x.brand`

```
x.brand
'Thales'
x.__dict__
{'brand': 'Thales'}
```

but y has nothing because is just a reference to `Robot.brand`

```
y.__dict__
{}
```

and Robot.brand has the class property `brand` with value `Thales`

```
Robot.__dict__
mappingproxy({'__module__': '__main__', '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'Robot' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'Robot' objects>, '__doc__': None, 'brand': 'Thales'})
```

See additional notes here: https://github.com/leocjj/0123/blob/master/Python/0123P_9_Classes_objects.txt